# Primary network internet in router is not working

Tags: networking, router, connection

I have a connection of 2 routers on one network. 1# router name is TP link 2# router name is IVOMI. The connection of IVOMI is connected to TP link so IVOMI is my secondary network and TP link is my primary network.
On initial stage both works fine but whenever we restart the computer the TP link network does not work. TP link is directly connected to my computer.
So we have to remove the IVOMI connection and connect the TP link connection then only internet starts.
Whenever we restart the computer the IVOMI dashboard open when we go on 192.168.0.1 and TP link dashboard don't open.

Is there anyway to fix this and setup the default dashboard as TP link dashboard instead of IVOMI dashboard.

Comment: Why do you have 2 routers on one network? Do they connect to different ISPs, or is one supposed to be acting as just a switch/wireless AP? If so, you need to configure it as such, not as a regular router.

Comment: They have connected to one ISP. I have duplex house so bought 2 routers to have good range of network.

Comment: It's not clear how both can connect to one ISP. Did they provide two routes to the internet, or is it, as I suspect, that you have put them 'in a line' so one connects to the net & the other connects to the first? If the latter you should really have bought an access point not a router. You'll have to check the manual for how to drop its functionality down to just an AP.

Comment: Yes both are connected to same ISP both the routers are using same ISP

Comment: You're not really answering my question. **How** are they connected? One to each of two different ISP connections, or one through the other?

Comment: Yes 2 routers are connected to same ISP and secondary router is connected to primary router with 2 different ISP wires but same ISP network